# Telnet send Ctrl-C

Tags: terminal, signals, terminal-emulator, serial-port, telnet

I use telnet to connect to a terminal server, which proxies the traffic to a RS-232 port.

Unfortunately when using some of the devices it is not possible to send the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> character (0x03). Instead of transmitting the character, it seems like the local client has catches the keystroke, and I'm left in "some-other-mode". What I wanted was just to send a character.

To debug this I have been playing around with:

```
^] toggle termdata
```

and

```
^] toggle options
```

Here is what happens when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on a terminal server which does not work:

```
telnet 10.10.129.101 2012
Trying 10.10.129.101...
Connected to termserv-val3 (10.10.129.101).
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> toggle options
Will show option processing.
^]
telnet> toggle termdata
Will print hexadecimal representation of terminal traffic.
SENT IAC IP
SENT DO TIMING MARK
```

Here is what happens on terminal servers which do work:

```
telnet termserv-val2 2012
Trying 10.10.128.93...
Connected to termserv-val2 (10.10.128.93).
Escape character is '^]'.

telnet> toggle options
Will show option processing.

telnet> toggle termdata
Will print hexadecimal representation of terminal traffic.
< 0x0   03
^C
```

I have tried `toggle localchars` but it did not make any difference.

I have also tried `mode character` which allowed me to send the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> character, but here I did not get any output back from the device.

How can I configure my telnet client to solve this?

Comment: What terminal server is this?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried turning off localchars in your telnet client?

```
bash$ telnet
telnet> toggle localchars
Won't recognize certain control characters.
telnet> open myhost
```

You may also be able to put this command in the `~/.telnetrc` file, depending on your version of telnet.

Comment: I have tried that (read the last part of the question)

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried using `toggle localchars`, but nothing changes. Using wireshark I can see that instead of 0x03 telnet sends `ff f4 ff fd 06`

Comment: I realize it has been ten years since the original question, but this recently popped up thanks to @mastupristi's recent comment.

You could try changing your terminal's intr character (on the local system) prior to running telnet.  Something like
`stty intr undef`
might do the trick.  There might be some other stty settings that could help, also... check `man stty` to see what your system has available.  On my mac, I have `ignbrk` which tells the terminal to ignore the break signal.

Answer (score 3):

You might try the 8-bit clean mode... it stops telnet from interpreting much of the data

```
telnet -8 host port
```

(This is a shot in the dark)

For the most part, you're on the right track, trying to get telnet to stop pre-interpreting keystrokes... such as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and others. 8bit mode should help.

Comment: I have tried this, it did not work. I did how ever find another solution: the terminal server can be configured to act as "TCP server mode" (default settings, which I have problems with), but if this is changed to "Real COM mode" things are working. I have no idea of what the actually differences are...

Comment: congratulations on finding a solution.  Always good to get a problem fixed.

Comment: Year... I'm not too happy with this solution, I would rather have it solved by making changes in my telnet client configuration

Comment: @Allan please submit your comment as an answer at mark it as the correct answer for fixing the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This might help, although it uses 3 other tools instead of `telnet`:

`echo 03 | xxd -r -p | nc host port`

Answer (score 1):

`^C` is a break character. You can send it with a telnet escape (default is `^]`) and then `send brk`.

Comment: Telnet's `BRK` sequence has implementation-specific significance on the receiving end and is not the same as sending the `ETX` (`^C`) character.  On Unixy systems, it usually means to do the `TCSBRK` `ioctl` on whatever TTY `telnetd` is using.  On serial devices, that often translates to holding the transmit line low for a quarter to half a second.

Comment: Not sure if it changes anything, but there's also `quit` command in telnet available.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this and not finding an answer by Googling. This is a very old thread, but I will leave this in case someone else comes here looking for a solution like I did.

1. Go into telnet command mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
2. Enter the command: `mode character`. This puts telnet into *character mode*, which for whatever reason now works as you would expect, <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and all.

Answer (score 0):

I used 'toggle options' and 'toggle termdata' to verify the situation at my site matches that of the original poster.
I was able to send the ^C (control-C) character specifically with the telnet command 'send ip' as described in the documentation.
In my case I put all 3 commands in my ~/.telnetrc

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
nc host port
```

If what you want is just connect to a server-port and interrupt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when needed. You can install `nc` with the `netcat` package.

P.S. the idea is taken from [@bambam's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232448/414186) but I don't know what's the meaning of `xxd` command that was used, and it works just fine without it for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue regarding not being able to send ^C (Control-C) to through the telnet session. Additionally, I was getting serial over the telnet session and there was a echo each time I interacted with the terminal. That is when I entered "a" in a linux bash shell I'd get "a" back twice and a "a: command not found" or I'd get two prompts back upon  that is:
$
$

I resolved this issue by ensuring the telnet session I was using was configured to use RFC2217 protocol. This corrected the anomalies of the serial terminal and the echos and "control" characters were properly interpreted. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2217

Answer (score 0):

In the non-working case, the output

```
SENT IAC IP
SENT DO TIMING MARK
```

indicates that either the TELNET LINEMODE option has been "successfully" negotiated with the remote end, or the `localchars` option is TRUE and the connection is using the "old line by line" mode.

In these situations, the Control-C keystroke is being sent as the corresponding Telnet protocol sequence (`IAC IP` = Interpret as Command: Interrupt Process).

But in the working case, the Control-C is simply sent out as ASCII character 0x03. That suggests Telnet is working in character mode, with no local interpretation of special characters.

So, it looks like you'd need to disable the LINEMODE option (`mode character`), and/or set LOCALCHARS to FALSE (`unset localchars`). Since you've tried both in isolation and it did not work, it looks like the terminal server specifically needs both of them together.

To do that, you could put this into your `~/.telnetrc`:

```
10.10.129.101
  mode character
  unset localchars

termserv-val3
  mode character
  unset localchars
```

(specified both by IP address and hostname, just in case you don't always refer to the terminal server in the same way)